# Get selected text in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wanna make an extension that takes the selected text and searches it in google translate
but I can't figure out how to get the selected text.

Here is my manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2, 
"name": "Saeed Translate",
"version": "1",
"description": "Saeed Translate for Chrome",
 "icons": {
    "16": "icon.png"
  },
"content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [ "content_script.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
   } ],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
"permissions": [
"contextMenus",
"background",
"tabs"
]

}
```

and my background.js file

```
var text = "http://translate.google.com/#auto/fa/";
function onRequest(request, sender, sendResponse) {
   text = "http://translate.google.com/#auto/fa/";
   text = text + request.action.toString();

 sendResponse({});
};

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({url:text});
});
chrome.contextMenus.create({title:"Translate '%s'",contexts: ["selection"]});
```

and my content_script.js file

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
var selectedText = sel.toString();
chrome.extension.sendRequest({action: selectedText}, function(response) {
  console.log('Start action sent');  
});
```

How do I get the selected text?

Comment: What is actually being sent? Is there an error message? Hard to tell if you don't give details about what's not working

Comment: Read the docs. Specifically the selectionText property: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#type-OnClickData

Comment: problem is that the selectedText in content_script.js is actually empty

Comment: @starshine Your `onClicked` event listeners makes no sense, read the docs to see how to discover the proper way to implement it: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#event-onClicked

Comment: @RobW that part of code works fine.
i tested that part.
so far the only problem is i can't take the highlighted text and use it.

Comment: @star It's not working fine, because you're not getting the selected text. Please read the documentation carefully: The [`onClicked` event](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#event-onClicked) handler receives two arguments. The first of type `onClickData`, the second of type `tab`. The type [`onClickData`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#type-OnClickData) has a property `selectionText` which contains the information which you're looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are making it a bit more complicated than it really is. You don't need to use a message between the content script and background page because the contextMenus.create method already can capture selected text. Try adjusting your creations script to something like:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({title:"Translate '%s'",contexts: ["all"], "onclick": onRequest});
```

Then adjust your function to simply get the info.selectionText:

```
function onRequest(info, tab) {
var selection = info.selectionText;
//do something with the selection
};
```

Please note if you want to remotely access an external site like google translate you may need to adjust your permissions settings.

Answer (score 2):

I would note - this is no longer valid response if you are moving to manifest version 3.  Manifest version 3 adds the concept of "service workers". https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/

You have to update several things, but the basic concept is the same.

**manifest.json**

```
"name": "Name of Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 3,
"description": "Description of Extension",
"permissions": [
      "contextMenus",
      "tabs",
      "activeTab"
],
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
},
```

**background.js**

```
//Setting up the function to open the new tab
function newTab(info,tab)
{
  const { menuItemId } = info

  if (menuItemId === 'anyNameWillDo'){
    chrome.tabs.create({
      url: "http://translate.google.com/#auto/fa/" + info.selectionText.trim()
    })}};

//create context menu options.  the 'on click' command is no longer valid in manifest version 3

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Title of Option",
  id: "anyNameWillDo",
  contexts: ["selection"]
});


//This tells the context menu what function to run when the option is selected

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(newTab);
```